# Unmerge/remove git branch that was merged into master dozens of commits ago

Tags: git

A large feature branch was approved and merged into master a week or so ago.  Right before release it was decided that it needs to be pulled, but several of the bug fixes that were merged into master **do** need to be released. The problem is that these bug fixes were either based off the point in master after where the feature was merged in, or they had a late version of master pulled into them.

```
             __bad-feature __       
master______/_________________\_____________________________________         
       \                             ^         /    \_bug-fix-1__/ 
        \___bug-fix-2_____[pull from master]__/
```

So I've tried just cherrypicking the bugfix commits.  This doesn't work because they largely have the feature merged in somewhere in the middle.  I was trying to figure out how to "replay" the individual bug fix commits over a "bad-feature" free version of master.  This sounds like a thing that should be possible?

Short of grabbing individual files in each bugfix branch, is there a better way to extract this branch from master?

Comment: I would add a branch to the commit before the merge, and then rebase master onto that new branch. You will likely hit conflicts though.

Comment: I've been messing around with `rebase`, trying to rebase the bug branches onto a rolled back master.  It doesn't seem to be working.  With your method, how would I specify which branches make it in and which don't?

Comment: You could use interactive rebase?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I was having issues because I was trying to cherrypick the commits at the end of the bugfix branches.  What I ended up doing is individually cherrypicking all the commits I wanted from the bugfix branches (and excluding the commits that tied into bad-feature).

Like @evolutionxbox suggested, I applied those commits to the end of a new branch that diverged from master right before the bad-feature.